# How to convert rotation matrix in to equivalent Quaternion using Eigen Library.

Tags: ros

Eigen library (http://goo.gl/cV5LY), which is used extensively in ROS and PCL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761909/eigen-convert-matrix3d-rotation-to-quaternion

Welcome neel, please take the time to look around and contribute to other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Eigen has a [Quaternion constructor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Quaternion.html#a3a01e15dcd661e921482d1df278e7bd7) that takes a rotation matrix.